# Creating multiple salt-engine process in rhel

Tags: python, python-3.x, salt-stack

I have installed the salt 3006.4 version which is based on one DIR ( python3.10 ). I have configured a py code to run via salt-engine whose config looks like this:

```
engines:
  - script:
      cmd: /opt/saltstack/salt/bin/python3.10 /srv/salt/engine/code_send.py
      output: json
      interval: 5
      onchange: true
```

But this is not running as expected by creating multiple processes.

I tried running py code individually, and it gave the expected output. But when I schedule it via the salt engine, it creates multiple processes.

I have lowered the version of Azure packages which was causing issues in different engine scripts.

A lowered version of pyyaml as well.

The library used in the above code is:

```
import os
import salt.config
import salt.utils.event
import salt.client
import json
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
import datetime
```

[image: multiple process being created]